# Free Port 80 for Caddy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, web-server, tcp

I'm trying to use port 80 on caddy but I'm getting an error saying the port is already in use. `listen tcp :80: bind: address already in use.` When I check to see what is using it this is what I get.

```
sonar@SonarQube:~$ netstat -an | grep ":80"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:42214          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:42222          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

How can I kill whatever is running on 80? Could running `sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/caddy cause it?` If so how do I undo it ?

#### update (after adding -p)

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:42768          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:42760          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

#### update 2

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1316/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:39152          91.189.95.83:80         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:49340          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:46654          91.189.88.161:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:48740          91.189.88.162:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:49314          52.176.58.79:80         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.5:49284          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1316/nginx -g daemo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `-p` switch to netstat so that you get the same of the program too. You'll need to run it as root/sudo as well.

> -p, --program
>
> Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

Comment: Thats whats showing in the update

Comment: The output cannot show program names when run as a normal user. Run it again with root privileges.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I say that in my answer.

Comment: I was referring to Antarr's updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You have nginx web server running on the server. Stop that with `service nginx stop` and you can start the other program.